# Wrong page size in zend REST

Tags: php, zend-framework

I have a problem using the page_size and max_page_size of the Zend REST controller for pagination.
I have the following config.php (snippet):

```
'zf-rest' => [
    Resource\DocumentResource::class => [
        'listener' => Resource\DocumentResource::class,
        ...
        'page_size' => 10,
        'min_page_size' => 1,
        'max_page_size' => 250,
        'collection_query_whitelist' => [
            'page_size',
        ],
    ],
],
```

If I make a REST call with

```
?page_size=50
```

everything works fine and I get a valid json. But if I make the call with

```
?page_size=250
```

(or an other value greater than 50) then I get an error:

```
HTTP 416 - Page size is out of range, maximum page size is 50
```

Comment: may be your "max_page_size" value overwrites. by some where, as all config file merged

Comment: I read that it can be a problem of checking the max_page_size against page_size_param because of preventing DoS attacks. But I haven't understand this fact.